# Python - How to open a file inside a module?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've something like this in my program:
A main script main.py inside a folder named 'OpenFileinaModule'. There's a folder called 'sub' inside it with a script called subScript.py and a file xlFile.xlsx, which is opened by subScript.py.

```
OpenFileinaModule/
             main.py
             sub/
             __init__.py   (empty)
             subScript.py
             xlFile.xlsx
```

Here is the code:

sub.Script.py:

```
import os, openpyxl

class Oop:
    def __init__(self):
        __file__='xlFile.xlsx'
        __location__ = os.path.realpath(
            os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
        print os.path.join(__location__, __file__)

        self.wrkb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(__location__, 
__file__),read_only=True)
```

main.py:

```
import sub.subScript
objt=sub.subScript.Oop()
```

When I execute main.py, I get the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\OpenFileInaModule\\xlFile.xlsx'
```

It jumps the sub folder... 
I've tried

```
__file__='sub/xlFile.xlsx'
```

But then the "sub" folder is duplicated:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\OpenFileInaModule\\sub\\sub/xlFile.xlsx'
```

How to open xlFile.xlsx with subScript.py from main.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're overriding `__file__` with `__file='xlFile.xlsx'`, do you mean to do this?

---

I think you want something like

```
import os
fname = 'xlFile.xlsx'
this_file = os.path.abspath(__file__)
this_dir = os.path.dirname(this_file)
wanted_file = os.path.join(this_dir, fname)
```

I'd suggest always using the absolute path for a file, especially if you're on windows when a relative path might not make sense if the file is on a different drive (I actually have no idea what it would do if you asked it for a relative path between devices).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Is this a common thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid using `__file__` and `__location__` to name your variables, these are more like builtin variables which might cause a confusion.

Note something here:

```
__location__ = os.path.realpath(
            os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

You have not included `sub` directory and the above joins only the CWD + `os.path.dirname(__file__)`. This doesn't get you to the file. Please read the documentation of [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname): `os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns an empty string here.

```
def __init__(self): 
    file = 'xlFile.xlsx'
    location = os.path.join('sub', file)
    location = os.path.abspath(location)             # absolute path to file
    location = os.path.realpath(location)           # rm symbolic links in path 
    self.wrkb = openpyxl.load_workbook(location)
```